# How can I customize Delve for my organization?

Tags: sharepoint, office365, customization, admin, delve

I have two issues I need help with.

1. I would like to customize the Delve user profile page for everyone in my organization. Ideally, I would like the background and header changed. I found this document and updated the theme for our organization, but apparently it doesn't work for Delve because I see no difference.   [Customize theme for your organization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/setup/customize-your-organization-theme?view=o365-worldwide)
2. I would like to change the titles of each of the sections in the profile to a different name (see attached screen shot).  I changed this in the manage user profiles section but it didn't affect the Delve user profile page.

I'm a newbie at O365/Sharepoint/Delve adminstration; any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1.Change to different image:

[image]

2.Change cover photo:

[image]

[image]

3.As you said, the section names in delve page could not be changed.

Comment: Thanks. I know how to change the themes for my own profile. Is there way to do it for my entire organization, so everyone starts out with the same default theme, customized to our brand?

Comment: As far as I know, Delve is tailored to each user, it's not possible to keep consistent for everyone.